# Mathematica - Numerical and Analytic plots don't overlap

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, integration

I want to plot simple functions like exponentials in *Mathematica*. 
I have a problem with the following code:

```
A[r_, c_] := Exp[-c r]
IntNum[r_?NumericQ, c_] := Integrate[A[t, c], {t, 0, r}]
IntAnal[r_, c_] := -(1/c) Exp[-c r]
Plot[{IntNum[r, 1], IntAnal[r, 1]}, {r, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

I don't understand why the two functions don't give same plot.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
A[r_, c_] := Exp[-c r]
Integrate[A[t, c], {t, 0, r}]
```

> (1 - E^(-c r))/c

and

```
(1 - E^(-c r))/c != -(1/c) Exp[-c r]
```